# How to obtain contextual embedding for a phrase in a sentence using BERT?

Tags: nlp, bert-language-model

I use https://github.com/UKPLab/sentence-transformers to obtain sentence embedding from BERT. Using this I am able to obtain embedding for sentences or phrases. For example: I can get embedding of a sentence like **"system not working given to service center but no response on replacement"**. I can also get embedding of a phrase like **"no response"**.

However I want to get embedding of **"no response"** in the context of **"system not working given to service center but no response on replacement"**. Any pointers on how to obtain this will be helpful. Thanks in advance.

I am trying to do this because the phrase **"no response"** has different contexts in different sentences. For example the context of "no response" is different in the following two sentences:
**"system not working given to service center but no response on replacement"
"we tried recovery procedure on the patient but there was no response"**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BERT returns one vector per input sub-word, so you need to get the vectors that correspond to the phrase you are interested in.

What is usually called a sentence embeddings is either the embedding of the technical symbol `[CLS]` that is prepended to the sentence before processing it with BERT; or an average of the contextual sub-word vectors. Because the `[CLS]` vector necessarily covers the entire sentence, you cannot get it just for a sub-phrase, but you can use the average of the sub-word embeddings of the phrase.

The package you are using, `sentence-transformers`, has a very simple user-friendly API, but I am afraid it is not strong enough to do this job. I'd suggest using [Huggingface's Transormers](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers). This package allows you to view how the sentence got tokenized and thus obtain the corresponding vectors.

Answer (score 0):

For a better phrase embedding, you can try Phrase-BERT for phrase embeddings.

- Paper: *Wang, Shufan, Laure Thompson, and Mohit Iyyer. "[Phrase-BERT: Improved Phrase Embeddings from BERT with an Application to Corpus Exploration.](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2109.06304.pdf)" EMNLP 2021*.
- [Code](https://github.com/sf-wa-326/phrase-bert-topic-model).

The paper also mentions related previous work, e.g. SentBERT and SpanBERT.

Not conditional though I believe.